# Java Timer parameter issue

Tags: java

I don't understand why my paramater in Affnage give an error. It's a fish. When I push a Button swim this fish go forward. But the problem is it don't stop at the distance d.
Thanks for help.

```
else if (e.getSource()==SwimUpDown){
            global.remove(droite);
            int d=Integer.parseInt (DeltaNage.getText());
            
            
            TimerTask repeatedTask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    for(int i =0; i<d; i++){
                    droite.Affnage(i);
                    droite.repaint();
                    global.add(droite);
                    global.repaint();
                    
                    
                    }
            
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
    
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(repeatedTask, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character 2) Method names should NOT start with an upper case character 3) We don't know what GUI this is for. Add the proper tag. If this is Swing then you should use a `javax.swing Timer`, not a util.Timer.

Comment: The code you have posted appears to be incomplete.  We do **NOT**, however, want to see your entire program.  Please compile a [mre], which **only** involves a timer.  No fish, no GUI, no distance d, just a timer.  But the example should be complete, we should be able to run it and see the problem.